# What is the first proof that you've done using induction?

Tags: soft-question, induction

Right now in class I'm learning induction and I'm having a hard time to grasp the concepts of it, especially strong induction which confuses me even further.

But out of curiosity, what is the first proof that you guys have done using mathematical induction?

Comment: I'm sure 99 out of 100 would say is to prove $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

Comment: In former USSR countries it is probably $1+ 2+\ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, the first problem from Demidovich's problem book on mathematical analysis. :-)

Comment: Binomial theorem ... Leibniz differentiation ...

Comment: I don’t remember what proof by induction I saw first; it’s been a *long* time since I was $11$, and it had to have been by then, since that’s when I first discovered one independently. It was a proof of a rather inelegant formula that I’d developed for reconstructing an $n$-th degree polynomial $f$ from $f(0),\ldots,f(n)$ using finite differences. I no longer remember the exact result; all I remember is that the proof was not very well organized but was definitely an inductive argument (as you would expect).

Comment: I concur with Danny, although we started from 0. ;)

Comment: First inductive proof that *I* did was probably proving that $ 1 + 3 \ldots + (2n - 1) = n^2$, but the first one I saw is definitely the one mentioned by Danny & njguliyev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One consequence of mathematical induction is the [Well-ordering principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle):

> Every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element.

In fact, it is possible that you must have internalized it long before even formally seeing the process of mathematical induction. So in a weird sense it could be the "first application" of it.

Comment: Interestingly, when I did this, we did it the other way round, stating the well-ordering principle axiomatically, and using it to prove that induction works.